# Saving custom profile fields

Tags: custom-field, filters, user-roles, profiles

I'm adding a custom profile field to users of a specific role, like this :

```
function add_custom_profile_fields( $fields ) {

    // get current user ID
    $user = new WP_User( $_GET['user_id'] );

    // get current user role
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        foreach ( $user->roles as $role ) {

            // filter roles
            if ($role == "paying_member"){
               $fields['paypal_account'] = 'Paypal account';        
            }
         }
     }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','add_custom_profile_fields',10,1);
```

The problem is, the field's value doesn't get saved. When I login as admin an I edit a user's profile. It somehow has to do with the fact that I'm filtering by user role, because when I remove that part, the values get saved perfectly.

EDIT : I think maybe the whole method is wrong, I'm going to try [this](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields) instead.

Comment: Would love to see how error objects feed into this design pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I was doing it wrong, here's a working solution, based on Justin Tadlock's [tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields).

```
<?php
/* Add custom profile fields (call in theme : echo $curauth->fieldname;) */ 

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

    <?php if(user_can($user->ID, "paying_member")) : ?>

        <h3>Extra profile information</h3>

        <table class="form-table">

            <tr>
                <th><label for="paypal_account">Paypal</label></th>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="paypal_account" id="paypal_account" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'paypal_account', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                    <span class="description">Please enter your Paypal account.</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    /* Copy and paste this line for additional fields. Make sure to change 'paypal_account' to the field ID. */
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'paypal_account', $_POST['paypal_account'] );
}


?>
```

The main addition to his code, is this line of code:

```
<?php if(user_can($user->ID, "paying_member")) : ?>
```

Which displays the custom fields only for users with the role of "paying_member" and admins.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the looping over roles and use [user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can)

The function takes either a capability *or a role* as param.

```
if (user_can($user->ID, "paying_member")) { 
    $fields['paypal_account'] = 'Paypal account';
}
```

Might also be worth checking into [current_user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) to skip the user lookup.

Comment: thanks that works too, but unfortunately saving the profile still doesn't save the values of the custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $_GET['user_id'] is not populated. You want to pull in the current user variable. Try this out:

```
function add_custom_profile_fields( $fields ) {
  global $current_user;
  if user_can($current_user, "paying_member") { 
    $fields['paypal_account'] = 'Paypal account';
  }
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: $_GET['user_id'] is populated. When I go (as an admin) to the Users section of WP and click on any user name to edit his profile, there is a "user_id" variable in the URL.

Comment: I quickly tested it out by doing var_dump( $_GET ); inside the function attached to user_contactmethods. I got NULL back. It's not a good idea to rely on user input anyway like that for security purposes. Loading the global current user will get you the user as verified by WordPress.

Comment: Ok let me re-explain. Let's say there is a user named "bob", who's role is "paying_member". Me, i'm user "admin". If I log in as "admin" and I go to "Users" in the WP backend, and I click on "bob" to edit his profile, on this profile page, the URL has a GET variable named "user_id". It is not user generated, it is generated by the WP core functions. Now, if I use "$current_user", that would return my own ID (because I'm logged as "admin") instead of "bob"'s ID (the one I'm really interested in). Do you see what I mean ?